# Jquery Mobile - Grid Breakpoint

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, responsive-design

I'm using the following jqm grid, i want each grid to stack up on top of each other as the orientation changes to portrait mode, i think currently the breakpoint is 45em.

I used the following syntax, but it didnt work, any suggestion?

//add a min/max class for 1200 pixel widths
$.mobile.addResolutionBreakpoints(1200);

//add min/max classes for 1200, and 1440 pixel widths
$.mobile.addResolutionBreakpoints([1200, 1440]);

Grid:

#### Grid B (33/33/33)

Block A
    Block B
    Block C

Comment: I guess it's easier to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/NYeW9/8/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by listening to `orientationchange` event.

First, create a custom class which will be added to blocks.

```
.blocks {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

On `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`, add that class if screen height is greater than width (*portrait*).

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
  if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
    $('.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c').addClass('blocks');
  }
});
```

On `orientationchange` add/remove that class.

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function (e) {
  if (e.orientation == 'landscape') {
    $('.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c').removeClass('blocks');
  }
  if (e.orientation == 'portrait') {
    $('.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c').addClass('blocks');
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BDunT/)**